# Lift and type safety

Tags: scala, lift

I am learning Lift now. When I read about templates, I understood that they have a lot of things which aren't typechecked at compilation time:

- Templates might contain references to non existent snippets
- SiteMaps might refer to non existent pages
- Snippet dispatch methods take string parameters where we can easily make a typo

Are there any alternatives to make this problems less severe, i.e. external code checker or options in the library which would allow do the same but in a type safe way? Or may be there is another web framework which is more strict in this relation (may be in other language).

Comment: I believe that for most such cases, it could be easy to write regexp-based validator. But while there is no such thing, you could try testing your code - proper testing should catch all those errors.

Answer (score 1):

Type checking is a compile time feature of strongly typed languages such as Scala or Java that allows the verification of the signatures and of the relationships among types. Such checks will prevent you from passing a parameter of type Banana when a parameter of type Meat is expected, or to assigning a String to a variable of type Int. Typically, in dynamic languages such as Ruby or Javascript, this is not possible

What you are looking for **is not a type checker**. You do not want to verify that your program is syntactically right, but rather that it behaves correctly, and the solution for that is called automated testing.

You are perfectly able to write code which is syntactically right, but behaving wrong:

```
public boolean isTrue(boolean value){
        return !value;
}
```

If you think it the other way around, how would you test a compile-time the correctness of a template which needs to be filled with some data?

```
 <!-- importing a snippet depending on the value of a variable -->
 <import src="${snippetName}.xml"/>
```

You can't, because all your variables at compile time have absolutely no value. That's why automated testing is important and writing test cases for your application cannot be replaced by compile-time checks.

Comment: For me, typechecking is about finding errors at compile time. And many of the things which aren't checked in lift can in theory be checked.

Comment: Typechecking is described here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_system . You are referring to static code analysis, which as you said can turn some runtime errors into compile-time errors. However, it is non trivial to write a static code analyzer, try it...

Comment: Type checking is a lightweight form of static analysis. What Konstantin wants is pretty feasible.

Comment: BTW, snippets in Lift is just a typical Scala class. Maybe checking parameters to those class constructor in template is not possible, but at least checking whether the snippet(class) does exist is feasible at compile time?

Comment: @BrianHsu - Nobody says it's not possible. It's just that nobody did it yet.